# How can I set derived static members before calling static functions of the base class

Tags: c#, generics, static, static-methods, derived-class

I have the following class:

```
class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    protected static string Source;

    public static List<T> Read()
    {
        return GetResource(Source);
    }
}
```

I want this class as baseclass for its functionality but every derived class has to have a different **Source**. My problem is that I can't assure the **Source** is set before **Read** is called. I know I could ask if the Source is set before **GetResource** is called but that's not the point. I need it to be set before *any* static member of my class is called.

Generic parameters can't have static Members so I can't take it from there.

I tried setting the **Source** in the derived class's static constructor but that will only be called when I call a member that is in the derived class and not in the Base.

I tried using a overridable method inside of the static Base constructor but such a method has to be static as well and static methods can't be overwritten.

When I set the Source manually, there is a chance that the **Read**-Function has already been called, so I *have to* set the **Source** before it can be called.

I know I could give **Source** as a parameter in **Read** but I want **Read** to be used without parameters.

Is there any way I can assure that the Source is Set before any other Member of my class is called, so that any dependent code is *inside* the derived class and doesn't have to be called by anyone using a derived class?

I basically want it to work like this:

```
class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    // somehow set Source
    Source = "This is my source";
}

class User
{
    private List<Derived> MyResources;

    public User()
    {
        MyResources = Derived.Read();
    }
 }
```

Note: the Source is basically a SQL statement so an Attribute or something like that wont be sufficient I think.

Comment: The derived class can have a constructor to initialize properties.

Comment: I know, I testet it but whenever I call any base-members the derived constuctor is not invoked. It is only invoked when I call a non-derived member. One that is not declared in Base.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way, but you *could* have the static constructor of `Base` look for derived types via reflection, and force their constructors to be called (`RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor`)... but that seems rather hacky (and it might cause problems with derived classes in other assemblies). I just wouldn't use static methods here if I were you.

Comment: I wish I could avoid it but since those static methods act like a factory I dont really have a choice but to use static methods.
I found one way to do it, even though I hoped to find another but its sufficient for now.

Comment: Do you really need the method and field to be static? What are you gaining by doing that? Without that restriction, subclasses can define constructors that require `source` as a parameter, which is a common pattern for required initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer. It is not as pretty as I hoped it would be but its the best I could come up with.

I will use an interface to force an Instance of T to have a certain method that provides my source.

```
interface ISource
{
    string GetSource();
}
```

I then implement that into my base class as such:

```
class Base<T> where T : Base<T>, ISource, new()
{
    public static List<T> Read()
    {
        // here I create an Instance to be able to call the Methods of T
        string source = (new T()).GetSource();
        return GetResource(source);
    }
}
```

The derived class:

```
class Derived : Base<Derived>, ISource
{
    public string GetSource()
    {
        return "This specific source";
    }
}
```

Usage as such:

```
class User
{
    public User()
    {
        List<Derived> myResources = Derived.Read();
    }
}
```

This of course will lead to every instance of **Derived** having the **GetSource**-method but for my scenario thats not a big deal. 
Also, since it creates an instance in the **Read**-method, this could be time consuming depending on the constructor of **Derived**. In my scenario it only has the standard constructor.

So use with caution.